# TensorFlow for Python 3 throws an error when installing on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python3, pip

Today I was attempting to install Google's TensorFlow for Python 3 without GPU. When I run the command:

```
sudo -H pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.wh
```

It throws the error:

```
tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

I am aware that there is already a question with the proper answer but that answer is for Python 2.7. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running on an x86_64 platform?

Comment: yes I am using a x86_64 system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2188#issuecomment-216186066, the solution is to download and rename the wheel and install using the renamed wheel:

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
mv tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl tensorflow-0.8.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow-0.8.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

If you are willing to wait a bit, the wheel for Python 3.5 should be out soon according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2188#issuecomment-220363241.

Comment: What should I rename the wheel to?

Comment: @jaw2233 See my answer.